# JSEncrypt into Python

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, rsa, jsencrypt

I'm reverse engineering a website. In website's code,

```
C = n("720d")

w = new C["JSEncrypt"];
w.setPublicKey(k.privateKey);

k = {
            privateKey: "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",
            encrypt: function() {
                var e = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : "";
                return w.encrypt(e)
    }
```

They defined `w` and `k` as above, and encrypt string with it like below.

```
k.encrypt("text goes here")
```

And encrypted output is below.

```
zrvsLtC+A+Ix8Dq/BoRqwRLaI72zOK0TgpJ7KdXEF6spBMYyv6boOzN0yhxA1cKCAImWsaFT7/JRTbBNj40b+qREkE7aNo9gymM4kHH/+u4oFm+2+vLZXBAWGApt9g585tpVLbwOa6ANE2CBLOt8MeZl4smteJq5rKMddRtDosodfdZWTTt8aTbJrgCgkFPzNyYmN+koxwsbZ1VW2MmLtCnIlEIZfDkOkU0WWzcOylLlpG6/Gs0LkRzsY8HoG4ttY0prb8JDlFcuSi+tdLptoSMABJlXZ0mZOAmcElye47QWlq3RlaxF8saJAjthJpsZABiwIRaVUt/X7i6Uunen9A==
```

I'm pretty sure that `w` is just `JSEncrypt`. Seems like when a string is given, It just encrypt string with `JSEncrypt` which has `k.privateKey` as public key.

I want to achieve the same thing with Python 3.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode,b64encode

pubkey = "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"
msg = "text goes here"
keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode())
emsg = b64encode(cipher_text)
print(emsg)
```

I'm trying with PyCrypto library, but since the public key looks different from others, error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pi/Desktop/test/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 682, in importKey
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

How can I achieve the same thing what JSEncrypt does with Python?

Comment: It is hard to help without specifying a Python library and without the first version of a Python code along with an appropriate problem description. Maybe this helps, JSEncrypt encrypts with the public key implicit in the private key.

Comment: @Topaco I just edited my question with more detail. Can you please check it out?

Comment: Even simpler than I first assumed. What is called `privateKey` in `k` is a _public_ key in X.509/SPKI format (hex encoded). I.e. the name is wrong and misleading. You only have to hex decode, i.e. `keyDER = bytes.fromhex(pubkey)` instead of `keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)`

Comment: @Topaco Oh, thanks. I really had no idea what type of that public key is. I switched `b64decode` to `bytes.fromhex` and It perfectly imports key now. But I got a problem. I think `Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5` is outdated and occurs `AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Nvm, `PyCryptodome` was the solution.

Comment: I missed that you are using PyCrypto. PyCrypto is deprecated, no longer maintained, has many bugs and is therefore a security risk. Switching to PyCryptodome is the right choice.